# Texture Not applying Blender 2.76

Tags: texturing, materials, uv, image

Now I have just started to use Blender and I have rushed through a small creation but when I add the .tga image to the UV/Image editor it doesn't apply itself to the actual object

By the way I have no idea what anything means since I just started.

[image: blender showing image and model]

Comment: Welcome to the site! The image editor is meant to show a "selected image", that means that there isn't a strict correlation between the shown object and the image itself in object mode. What image appears in the editor if you enter edit mode?

Comment: Thanks for the welcome! I know what you mean and now I feel a bit dumb... I've selected the image and THEN opened the image so the texture now applys itself. Thank you so much!

Comment: Glad it helped, though I'm not sure about the "selected to opened" passage. Consider to write an answer to your own question with the solution (and mark as accepted) of the problem for future generations.

Comment: Don't forget to create a texture in the material of the object.  Just because the image is used in the 3D preview doesn't mean that is what the rendered object will look like.